# Quickly Converting Between Expanded and Compacted Trees

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, tree, decision-tree

I have two tree formats (an exapanded tree and a compacted tree). They are sorta decision trees, sorta tries. Each node can have an arbitrary number of children. The leaf nodes also contain data. The expanded tree is essentially the logic expanded out with no ANDs/ORs in each subtree/node. The compacted tree basically collects expanded nodes together so humans can edit easier (reduces duplication).

I'm looking for an efficient way to convert between the two trees as my current algorithm is rather naive (it's slightly better than O(n^2)). It's starting to break down as I'm hitting ~2 million nodes in the expanded tree.

Is there a keyword I can search for similar problems? It's sorta "inverting" the trees (data in nodes in one tree becomes the path in the other tree), though "inverting a binary tree" means a different operation (more like horizontal mirroring of order). Decision trees <-> table conversion seems possibly relevant, though slightly different data formats?

Constraints:

- The expanded tree format can't really be changed easily, but the compacted tree format could be modified if a substantial speed increase could be gained by changing it.
- There are 2 million expanded nodes currently, with an upper limit of 10 million nodes total in the future years (realistically probably around 5 million).
- Ideally limit to 6GB total JVM memory so it can be done client side, but willing to move it to server machines with 30GB if we can make it orders of magnitude faster using more RAM (though then we start hitting network transfer latency).
- In a perfect world conversion would take < 30 seconds. Right now I'm at about 3-4 minutes.

Example expanded and compacted trees:
[image: Example Expanded and Compacted Trees]

What happened when going from expanded -> compacted:

- The paths and data basically inverted (expandedTree data -> compactedTree path and expandedTree path -> compactedTree data)
  ** The expanded node data was used to construct the paths in the compacted tree (in parens in expanded nodes)
  ** The paths in expanded nodes went into the key/value map in the data of the compacted nodes (combining duplicates as needed)
- Expanded nodes data2 and data3 compacted into a single node in the compacted tree because their compacted paths were the same (some/expanded/path) and their key/value pairs could be ORed together (key1 == valu1 AND (key2 == value2 OR value4))
- Expanded nodes data2 and data4 couldn't be compacted because their compacted paths were not equal.
- Expanded nodes data1 and data2+data3 couldn't be compacted because their paths are not compatible (data1 has an additional constraint on key3=value3 that data2+data3 don't)

To give more details on the formats:

Expanded:

- The path down the tree is a series of key/value pairs. So it basically acts like a decision tree or trie.
- Only leaf data nodes are important for the compacted tree. The intermediate path nodes can be re-generated easily enough as they contain no data.
- Each data node has some ids that are important to remember as this is the master (persisted) format.
- Each data node stores a compacted path in it to know where to go when converted into the compacted tree. This uses up a lot of space (and time during conversion), so doing this another way would be ideal. I'm thinking about removing user-defined groupings alltogether (remove this string from expanded nodes) and instead compact equal nodes up the tree during compacted tree conversion, though not sure how much speed will be gained by doing this and the user-defined groupings are currently useful to users.

Compacted:

- The path down the tree is stored in the expanded tree nodes and not related to where a given node was in the expanded path (in a perfectly balanced, complete tree, the leftmost leaf and rightmost leaf could have the same compact path and thus end up in the same compacted node, even though they are in different expanded subtrees).
- Ids aren't important here (in fact if there were none for humans to mess with it would be ideal). But do we do need to remeber the expanded tree ids in order to reconstruct the expanded tree perfectly somehow. This is a tricky part!
- The path from the expanded tree ends up in a key/value map in the data nodes of the compacted nodes (see example). This basically groups expanded nodes together with ANDs and ORs into a single compacted node (hence the compacting). This seems like a common problem that someone has to have solved already when compacting logical expressions?

Thanks!